# For each matching element in two lists add a list and extend

Tags: python

For some reason my brain's not working.

I have two sorted list-like objects:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]

>>> b = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

From this, I need to get:

```
>>> a = [ [1,[1,1]], [2,[2,2,2]], [3,[3,3,3]], 4]
```

Codewise, I was thinking this...

```
>>> i = 0
>>> first = True
>>> for num in b:
...    if num == a[i]:
...       if first:
...          a[i] = [a[i],[num]]
...          first = False
...       else:
...          a[i][1].append(num)
...    else:
...       first = True
...       if a[i+1] == num:
...          a[i] = [a[i+1],[num]]
...       else:
...          print 'problem'
```

But I keep getting confused. What is an efficient way to solve this? I feel like recursion, maybe, but I can't figure that out either.

Comment: That's an... interesting transformation.  Looks like you are trying to reimplement what a `Counter` does, just in a much less usable manner.

Comment: `for value in new_list: value,count = value[0],len(value[1])` not MUCH less usable....

Comment: @adsmith yes but 1) that doesn't work, because of his heterogeneous format for `4` and 2) even if you address that, single lookups are O(n) as opposed to O(1).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JoelCornett The real case is a bit more complicated.  I'm using sqlalchemy to pull a 'list' (keyed tuple) of objects and a 'list' of time series data (by month).  An ID number exists in the object list and there are corresponding IDs in the time series data. I then need to add an attribute to the object list[ID] with __setattr__('attr name', [time_series_list_for_this_object]). Haven't been sleeping much lately :(.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the data is already sorted, you can group `b` based on the number and create a dictionary using dictionary comprehension. In the next pass over the keys (`a`) you can get the elements from the dictionary corresponding to the elements of `a` and create a new list.

```
a, b = [1,2,3,4], [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
from itertools import groupby

d = {k:list(grp) for k, grp in groupby(b)}
# {1: [1, 1], 2: [2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3, 3]}

print [[k, d[k]] if k in d else k for k in a]
# [[1, [1, 1]], [2, [2, 2, 2]], [3, [3, 3, 3]], 4]
```

Comment: Ooh that's pretty! Can you document it a little better? I don't have a strong grasp of `itertools.groupby`

Comment: @adsmith I added a little bit of explanation, please check.

Comment: cute! I wonder performance-wise how the `groupby` dict comp measures up to my solution below using `collections.Counter` and nested list comps.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]

bb = Counter(b)

new_list = [[el_a,[el_a for _ in range(bb[el_a])]] for el_a in a]
# [[1, [1, 1]], [2, [2, 2, 2]], [3, [3, 3, 3]], [4, []]]
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy-reading option:

```
finallist = []
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
pos = 0
for item in a:
    mylist = [item,[]]
    while pos < len(b) and b[pos] == item :
        mylist[1].append(item)
        pos += 1
    finallist.append(mylist)

print finallist
```